# Namespace with Qualifier is redundant

Tags: namespaces, resharper

I used to use the fully qualified namespace outside of the namespace as below.

```
using D.E.F
namespace A.B.C
{
```

I recently started using ReSharper, and I noticed a message *Qualifier is redundant* corresponding to the qualifier **D**. As a result I can use the namespace like

```
namespace A.B.C
{
using E.F
```

Please note that I'm not using **using D.E.F** inside the namespace.

Is this a new feature in Visual Studio 2012 which Resharper is trying to report. I still don't understand how the compiler understands the real namespace is **D.E.F** not **E.F**?